# React app doesnt refresh or update changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have been browsing the web to find an answer to my problem. I made a fresh react app, and if I make changes to app.js file - nothing happens. I have to run the 'npm start' command to see any changes in App.js and index.js files ( index.html updates changes after refresh ).

Anyways, I tried a few things such as adding a start script to package.json

```
FAST_REFRESH=fast npm start
```

as well as making a .env file with

```
FAST_REFRESH=fast
```

and even installing custom npm/webpack react refresh packages, or making a new project in a different directory. But it refuses to comply!

I'm on Windows.

I'm looking for any other ideas on how to fix this problem.

EDIT:

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "practice-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "FAST_REFRESH=false vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Package-lock.json

```
  "name": "practice-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "practice-project",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.6.4",
        "vite": "^3.1.0"
      }
    },
```

EDIT2:
Ok, I got it to work on my WSL/Ubuntu. No idea why it didn't want to work on windows though.

Comment: Show your configuration. How did you create the app?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski hey thanks for answering, I first used npx create-react-app. The app wasn't refreshing already, so I tried VITE with npm create vite. But the same thing is happening after both. I uploaded my package-lock.json and package.json